# Make Android Sources Read Only - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, readonly, android-source

I recently started using Android Studio and noticed that you can also edit the Android Source Files. The main android.app.Activity java file can also be edited. And the changes persist even after closing the file.

In Eclipse all such source files are read only.

I don't want to dismantle or mess with the Android Source Files. 
It does not give me a compile error even if there are errors in those source files. 
So I assume Android Studio does not compile those files.

My queries.

Is it safe to edit those files? 
Is it possible to make those files read only. So that I don't have to be careful. 
Any way to revert to the original copy of the source files if somehow you changed it before?

Answer (score 0):

You already use tools like GIT or SVN?

That are version control system (VCS). With that tools you save the current code.

When you do changes, you can easy compare them with latest saved code. So you can detect each change (on a file, line, or letter) and then revert or saved it as your current code.

Both are free and for git exist a great free web service at http://github.com

Comment: yeah, Thank you.
But is there a way to make those source files read only?

Comment: I think no. Not direct with android studio. But when you use Linux based OS you can make files read only for certain user groups. But I can't imagine why I should make resources read only.

Comment: The Android Framework Source Files downloaded using SDK manager. We don't want to change the source code  in it even by accident.